# GWT : How to remove element from it's outermost?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have one [Anchor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) widget as

```
<td class="GAS3MDBHJ">
  <div class="GAS3MDBJJ">
    <a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#export">Export</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I would like to remove this anchor element from it's root. How can I achieve it.

If I use [widget.getParentElement()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Node.html#getParentElement%28%29) , I need to write as ...

> myanchor.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement().removeFromParent();

Now it is in third level.If my widget is in level 7 or 8 or 9 , am I need to write [getParentElement()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Node.html#getParentElement%28%29) repeatedly ?
Has there anyway for fast code ?

> *I don't want to get it's parent element, I really want to get was **outermost element***.

Comment: I want to remove my widget from `td` tag.

Comment: The outermost parent would return <html> right? So what exactly do you wanna achieve? Removing the anchor as well as all its ancestors excluding the <td> element?

Comment: Where is the issue in simply calling `anchor.removeFromParent();`? It works perfectly.

Comment: @z00bs yes! you are right. I thought stupid thing. As you said "the outermost parent was <html>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply call

```
anchor.removeFromParent();
```

It will remove the entire anchor element with all of its inner HTML. The result will be exactly the same if you call

```
anchor.getElement().removeFromParent();
```

because anchor.getElement() will give you the outer most element of this widget, just as you wanted.

If you start calling getParentElement(), you will remove more than your anchor widget.